# Cannot read property 'length' from null

Tags: javascript, null, netsuite

In SuiteScript, I am attempting to run a saved search but I got an error **"Cannot read property 'length' from null"** .
See my code :

```
 if(search.length>0){
    layout += '<tr height="1cm">';
    layout += '</tr>';
    layout += '<tr>';
    layout += '<td align="right" border="0px" colspan="8" style=\"font-size:12px;\">';
    for(var x = 0;x<search.length;x++){
    layout += iE(search[x].getText('account'))+'<br/>';
    }
    layout +=  '</td>';
    }
```

also I tried this code also but same result.

```
if(search!==null %% search.length!==null){
            layout += '<tr height="1cm">';

            layout += '</tr>';
            layout += '<tr>';
            layout += '<td align="right" border="0px" colspan="8" style=\"font-size:12px;\">';
            for(var x = 0;x<search.length;x++){
                layout += iE(search[x].getText('account'))+'<br/>';

            }
            layout +=  '</td>';
            }
```

Comment: Try logging ´search´ to console, and see what it is

Comment: what do you mean? sorry newbie in NetSuite

Comment: just do `if(search)`

Answer (score 1):

try using &&

```
if(search!==null && search.length!==null){
```

Answer (score 1):

Please replace the `%%` by `&&` (as @scarlet witch suggested) and add little more context.

What I can deduce from your question is that the global variable search is set null at some point of your code, since this is a [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it) a lot things could be wrong here, I would recommend use [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/add-breakpoints) and check whats happening.

Please update your question so we may be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to check if it's array or not

```
function isArray(obj){
   return !!obj && Array === obj.constructor;
}
```

and use it in if statement like

```
if(isArray(search)){
   // implementation
}
```

i don't know why you check `search.length !== null` if you want to check if there is element in array or not you should check by `search.length >=0`.

`ArrayVar.length` never be null unless you explicitly set `ArrayVar.length = null`. it will be 0 by default.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that search is undefined when the execution reaches this line. Try using

```
if(typeof search !== "undefined" && search.length!==null){
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing:

`if(search!==null && search.length!==null){`

The AND operator is `&&`

Also try
`if(search && search.length>0){`

Answer (score 0):

Just use : `if(search)`

Note that using `!==` or `===` means, JavaScript checks for both type of the variable and value.([Strict Equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()))

**Examples:**

```
var search = "";

search !== null; //true
search.length !== null; //true
search.length === "0"; //false
search.length === 0; //true
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you populating the `search` variable? Is it supposed to be the results of a search?

`nlapiSearchRecord` returns `null` when there are no matching results for your search.

The simplest way to check this is just something like:

```js
if (search && search.length) {
    // Process results
}
```

The pattern that I follow whenever I am working with searches and results is to create one function that performs the search and always returns an array, and another function containing the logic for processing a single search result.

```js
function findRecords() {
    var filters = [...];
    var columns = [...];
    // The `|| []` clause ensures we always return an array, never null
    return nlapiSearchRecord(recordType, null, filters, columns) || [];
}

function processResult(result) {
    // Process a single result
}

// Run search and process all results
findRecords().map(processResult);
```

You can read more about handling `null` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null